# What is ActionMapping, RenderMapping?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, portlet

I know its part of the spring framework, but i don't understand it. Where can learn more about spring framework, more specifically how webapps are built using these type of annotations.

Namely, right now i need to test a function, which is not called from anywhere in the source (that i can find using eclipse), but has the annotation ActionMapping, no idea how to test it, because i dont know where its called from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@ActionMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/portlet/bind/annotation/ActionMapping.html) is part of the [Spring MVC portlet framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html), start there for reference. If you need to write unit or integration tests, have a look at the [Spring testing guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html), and at the section [mock objects for the portlet api](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#mock-objects-portlet).

Comment: Unfortunately they forgot to mention @ActionMapping in the Spring MVC portlet framework guide you referenced. :(